# Magento: Authorize.net AVS Code, Transaction ID and Auth Code

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9, authorize.net

I need to store the AVS Code, Auth Code and Transaction ID in the "additional_information" field in the sales_flat_order_payment table.  How would I go about doing this?  This would only be for Authorize.net transactions.  My Magento version is 1.9.1.

Currently the field looks like this:

`a:1:{s:15:"authorize_cards";a:1:{s:32:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";a:14:{s:2:"id";s:32:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";s:16:"requested_amount";s:0:"";s:15:"balance_on_card";s:0:"";s:13:"last_trans_id";s:1:"0";s:16:"processed_amount";s:5:"56.67";s:7:"cc_type";s:2:"VI";s:8:"cc_owner";N;s:8:"cc_last4";s:4:"1111";s:12:"cc_exp_month";s:2:"12";s:11:"cc_exp_year";s:4:"2025";s:11:"cc_ss_issue";N;s:17:"cc_ss_start_month";N;s:16:"cc_ss_start_year";N;s:15:"captured_amount";s:5:"56.67";}}}`

There's a `cc_avs_status` field, however, I'd prefer to keep that data in the `additional_information` field.  Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento won't allow you to get credit card information and it's not stored in the database.  However, in the configuration settings for Authorize.net, there is an option for Merchant Email Address.  When a credit card transaction is sent through on your site, an email will be sent to this address with details of the transaction including AVS code, prices, customer information and so on.  Make sure you put your email address in there and you'll get an email as soon as the transaction is processed.  It actually arrives before the order confirmation email.  `Admin > System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Authorize.net`